# How to hide/show a drop down list item based on certain condition?

Tags: c#, html, webforms

Here is my front-end code for drop down:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSearch" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Ref No" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Name" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="contact" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make it so a drop down will appear if for example a check box was ticked or any condition was met?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the item using `.FindByValue` or `.FindByText` methods on `ddlSearch.Items`. Then setting the item's `.Enabled` property to `false` will hide it on UI.

So, for example, if you needed to hide an item having value "1", you could do:

```
ddlSearch.Items.FindByValue("1").Enabled = false;
```

Note that in production code you would want to have null checking after `FindByValue`, but I have omitted it for simplicity. For example, here's how you could check for nulls:

```
var listitem = ddlSearch.Items.FindByValue("1");
if (listitem != null) 
{
    listitem.Enabled = false;
}
else 
{
    // Throw an exception or display an error that the list item wasn't found.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I tried in this method, but couldn't get the result as expected.

Comment: So what exactly happened? Are you still able to see that item on UI?

Comment: Yes, the items are visible still. What is this point, i couldn't get  ''Note that in production code you would want to have null checking after FindByValue, but I have omitted it for simplicity.''

Comment: I am not sure why it wouldn't work. Can you add relevant code? Regarding null checking, `FindByValue` will return null if there is no matching list item. So you should check for null before setting `Enabled = false`.

Comment: if(rbtnModule == 1)
{
ddlSearch.Items.FindByValue("5").Enabled = false;
}

Comment: hmm that should work. Did you try stepping through the code during debugging to see if it works? @Dennis

Comment: I have written only this code, how to write that null checking code?

Comment: @Dennis Updated the answer.

Comment: @Dennis You're welcome. You can mark an answer as accepted if it works for you. Same goes for any of the old questions you might have asked.